# How to find tables being used in oracle cursor?

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor, oracle19c

I have list of package, their corresponding procedures and their corresponding cursors and attributes used in those cursors.

Can someone please help me how I can identify corresponding table names of those attributes?

I am using SQL Developer with 19c as oracle version.

Thanks

Comment: [PL/Scope](https://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/plscope-identifiers.shtml) can list the tables and their column names occurring in stored PL/SQL code (in [user_identifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/refrn/ALL_IDENTIFIERS.html)), and their full SQL text (in [user_statements](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/refrn/ALL_STATEMENTS.html)). However I am not sure exactly what you want to report.

Answer (score 0):

A "cursor" in Oracle terminology is a prepared SQL statement, identified by a `sql_id` in the shared pool. To see what objects that cursor depends on, assuming you have the `SELECT ANY DICTIONARY` privilege, you can query its execution plan details like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       object_owner,
       object_name,
       object_node
  FROM v$sql_plan
 WHERE sql_id = 'c7d4p6r0xs00f' -- replace with your sql_id
```

Now be aware that if it uses an index and gets everything it needs from the index and doesn't actually visit the table underneath, you'll see the index but not the table. So you might want to augment the query to cover yourself in that event:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       object_owner,
       object_name,
       object_node,
       CASE WHEN (operation LIKE '%INDEX%') THEN (SELECT MAX(i.table_name)
                                                    FROM all_indexes i
                                                   WHERE i.index_name = sp.object_name
                                                     AND i.owner = sp.object_owner) 
       END index_table_name
  FROM v$sql_plan sp
 WHERE sql_id = 'c7d4p6r0xs00f'
```

Your question also makes mention of packages and procedures. If you need to know what objects those depend on, as they are compiled code Oracle records their dependencies so it can invalidate them if something goes wrong with one of the dependencies. You can query it like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM all_dependencies
 WHERE owner = 'MYSCHEMA'
   AND name = 'MYPACKAGE_OR_PROCEDURE_OR_FUNCTION_OR_WHATEVER'
```

The only thing this will omit is any objects you use in dynamic SQL (e.g. within `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` or `OPEN FOR` as those don't create dependencies that Oracle tracks). For those you have to run the code and then inspect `v$sql_plan`.

It is also possible that by "cursor" you meant a named `CURSOR` or `REF CURSOR` variable created by PL/SQL (which are not cursors themselves, but handles to refer to cursors). If so, and if it was defined statically, not dynamically, then its objects will be in the defining procedure's dependency list (use `all_dependencies`). If it was dynamically defined, however, your best bet would be to add a  hint that uniquely identifies each one, then run the code, then you can query `v$sql` and use the hint in the SQL statement text to find your cursors and use `v$sql_plan` to get their objects, as shown above.

Lastly, you mention "attributes" by which I'm guessing you mean columns in a result set. It's not possible to get this list cleanly without manually extracting it from the SQL or PL/SQL text itself. An advanced technique that might be worth looking into for a particularly brave soul would be to look at the outermost projection from the plan (should be the lowest `id`), but the output would need some additional work to clean it up and I haven't proven this out beyond a few simple tests:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT projection,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sql_id,child_number ORDER BY id) seq
          FROM v$sql_plan
         WHERE sql_id = 'd747aacbc0hhv'
           AND projection IS NOT NULL)
WHERE seq = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the code below. It was quite usefull to me so far and works with different types of objects (table, view, package body ...). Basic instructions are within the code. If I got you right you need to find dependencies of a package object (don't know about atributes mentioned) if that is the case then for ObjectType parameter put 'PACKAGE BODY' you will need to provide the object owner and object name too.
Here is the code returning object dependencies upto 6 level deep:

```sql
--  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--  Shows objects that given object depends on
--      
--          --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--          NOTE :
--              The code uses recursions - so it is highly advisable to use it just for one object at a time to prevent infinite recursions 
--
--              Source is system table DBA_DEPENDENCIES to which you'd need to have access to
--              If not use ALL_DEPENDENCIES instead
--          --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--
--  Code could be used in SQL> or Oracle Developer 
--  
--  Parameters are of type VarChar2 (They Are Not Case Sensitive) and should be provided within single quates:
--      like    -   OwnerName -> 'scott'        ObjectName -> 'my_view'     ObjectType -> 'VIEW'
--
--  Resulting format:   --->    [Object_Type] "ObjectName" (owner.OwnerName)    <---
--  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WITH
    obj AS
        (   Select &OwnerName "OWNED_BY", &ObjectName "OBJ_NAME", &ObjectType "OBJ_TYPE" From Dual  ), 
--  ---------------------------------------
    obj_deps_1 AS
        (   Select
                o.OBJ_NAME "OBJ_NAME",
                o.OBJ_TYPE "OBJ_TYPE",
                o.OWNED_BY "OBJ_OWNED_BY",
                --
                CASE WHEN d.REFERENCED_OWNER IN('SYS', 'PUBLIC') THEN Null ELSE d.REFERENCED_NAME END "REF_OBJ_NAME_1",
                CASE WHEN d.REFERENCED_OWNER IN('SYS', 'PUBLIC') THEN Null ELSE d.REFERENCED_TYPE END "REF_OBJ_TYPE_1",
                CASE WHEN d.REFERENCED_OWNER IN('SYS', 'PUBLIC') THEN Null ELSE d.REFERENCED_OWNER END "REF_OBJ_OWNED_BY_1"
                --
            From 
                obj o 
            Inner Join
                ALL_DEPENDENCIES d ON(d.OWNER = Upper(o.OWNED_BY) And d.NAME = Upper(o.OBJ_NAME) And d.TYPE = Upper(o.OBJ_TYPE))
        ),
    obj_deps_6 AS
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT
                o.OBJ_NAME "OBJ_NAME",
                o.OBJ_TYPE "OBJ_TYPE",
                o.OBJ_OWNED_BY "OBJ_OWNED_BY",
                --
                o.REF_OBJ_NAME_1 "REF_OBJ_NAME_1",
                o.REF_OBJ_TYPE_1 "REF_OBJ_TYPE_1",
                o.REF_OBJ_OWNED_BY_1 "REF_OBJ_OWNED_BY_1",
                --
                CASE WHEN d2.REFERENCED_OWNER IN('SYS', 'PUBLIC') THEN Null ELSE d2.REFERENCED_NAME END "REF_OBJ_NAME_2",
                CASE WHEN d2.REFERENCED_OWNER IN('SYS', 'PUBLIC') THEN Null ELSE d2.REFERENCED_TYPE END "REF_OBJ_TYPE_2",
                CASE WHEN d2.REFERENCED_OWNER IN('SYS', 'PUBLIC') THEN Null ELSE d2.REFERENCED_OWNER END "REF_OBJ_OWNED_BY_2",
                --
                CASE WHEN d3.REFERENCED_OWNER IN('SYS', 'PUBLIC') THEN Null ELSE d3.REFERENCED_NAME END "REF_OBJ_NAME_3",
                CASE WHEN d3.REFERENCED_OWNER IN('SYS', 'PUBLIC') THEN Null ELSE d3.REFERENCED_TYPE END "REF_OBJ_TYPE_3",
                CASE WHEN d3.REFERENCED_OWNER IN('SYS', 'PUBLIC') THEN Null ELSE d3.REFERENCED_OWNER END "REF_OBJ_OWNED_BY_3",
                --
                CASE WHEN d4.REFERENCED_OWNER IN('SYS', 'PUBLIC') THEN Null ELSE d4.REFERENCED_NAME END "REF_OBJ_NAME_4",
                CASE WHEN d4.REFERENCED_OWNER IN('SYS', 'PUBLIC') THEN Null ELSE d4.REFERENCED_TYPE END "REF_OBJ_TYPE_4",
                CASE WHEN d4.REFERENCED_OWNER IN('SYS', 'PUBLIC') THEN Null ELSE d4.REFERENCED_OWNER END "REF_OBJ_OWNED_BY_4",
                --
                CASE WHEN d5.REFERENCED_OWNER IN('SYS', 'PUBLIC') THEN Null ELSE d5.REFERENCED_NAME END "REF_OBJ_NAME_5",
                CASE WHEN d5.REFERENCED_OWNER IN('SYS', 'PUBLIC') THEN Null ELSE d5.REFERENCED_TYPE END "REF_OBJ_TYPE_5",
                CASE WHEN d5.REFERENCED_OWNER IN('SYS', 'PUBLIC') THEN Null ELSE d5.REFERENCED_OWNER END "REF_OBJ_OWNED_BY_5",
                --
                CASE WHEN d6.REFERENCED_OWNER IN('SYS', 'PUBLIC') THEN Null ELSE d6.REFERENCED_NAME END "REF_OBJ_NAME_6",
                CASE WHEN d6.REFERENCED_OWNER IN('SYS', 'PUBLIC') THEN Null ELSE d6.REFERENCED_TYPE END "REF_OBJ_TYPE_6",
                CASE WHEN d6.REFERENCED_OWNER IN('SYS', 'PUBLIC') THEN Null ELSE d6.REFERENCED_OWNER END "REF_OBJ_OWNED_BY_6"
            FROM
                obj_deps_1 o
            LEFT JOIN
                ALL_DEPENDENCIES d2 ON(d2.NAME = Nvl(o.REF_OBJ_NAME_1, 'no_object') And d2.TYPE = Nvl(o.REF_OBJ_TYPE_1, 'no_type'))
            LEFT JOIN
                ALL_DEPENDENCIES d3 ON(d3.NAME = Nvl(d2.REFERENCED_NAME, 'no_object') And d3.TYPE = Nvl(d2.REFERENCED_TYPE, 'no_type'))
            LEFT JOIN
                ALL_DEPENDENCIES d4 ON(d4.NAME = Nvl(d3.REFERENCED_NAME, 'no_object') And d4.TYPE = Nvl(d3.REFERENCED_TYPE, 'no_type'))
            LEFT JOIN
                ALL_DEPENDENCIES d5 ON(d5.NAME = Nvl(d4.REFERENCED_NAME, 'no_object') And d5.TYPE = Nvl(d4.REFERENCED_TYPE, 'no_type'))
            LEFT JOIN
                ALL_DEPENDENCIES d6 ON(d6.NAME = Nvl(d5.REFERENCED_NAME, 'no_object') And d6.TYPE = Nvl(d5.REFERENCED_TYPE, 'no_type'))
        )
SELECT 
    REPLACE('[' || OBJ_TYPE || '] "' || OBJ_NAME || '" (owner.' || OBJ_OWNED_BY || ')', '[] "" (owner.)', 'None') "OBJECT",
    REPLACE('[' || REF_OBJ_TYPE_1 || '] "' || REF_OBJ_NAME_1 || '" (owner.' || REF_OBJ_OWNED_BY_1 || ')', '[] "" (owner.)', 'None') "DEPENDENCY_1",
    REPLACE('[' || REF_OBJ_TYPE_2 || '] "' || REF_OBJ_NAME_2 || '" (owner.' || REF_OBJ_OWNED_BY_2 || ')', '[] "" (owner.)', 'None') "DEPENDENCY_2",
    REPLACE('[' || REF_OBJ_TYPE_3 || '] "' || REF_OBJ_NAME_3 || '" (owner.' || REF_OBJ_OWNED_BY_3 || ')', '[] "" (owner.)', 'None') "DEPENDENCY_3",
    REPLACE('[' || REF_OBJ_TYPE_4 || '] "' || REF_OBJ_NAME_4 || '" (owner.' || REF_OBJ_OWNED_BY_4 || ')', '[] "" (owner.)', 'None') "DEPENDENCY_4",
    REPLACE('[' || REF_OBJ_TYPE_5 || '] "' || REF_OBJ_NAME_5 || '" (owner.' || REF_OBJ_OWNED_BY_5 || ')', '[] "" (owner.)', 'None') "DEPENDENCY_5",
    REPLACE('[' || REF_OBJ_TYPE_6 || '] "' || REF_OBJ_NAME_6 || '" (owner.' || REF_OBJ_OWNED_BY_6 || ')', '[] "" (owner.)', 'None') "DEPENDENCY_6"
FROM
    obj_deps_6
ORDER BY
    OBJ_NAME, OBJ_TYPE,
    REF_OBJ_NAME_1, REF_OBJ_TYPE_1,
    REF_OBJ_NAME_2, REF_OBJ_TYPE_2,
    REF_OBJ_NAME_3, REF_OBJ_TYPE_3,
    REF_OBJ_NAME_4, REF_OBJ_TYPE_4,
    REF_OBJ_NAME_5, REF_OBJ_TYPE_5
```